# PHP how do I compare the date from the database with the current date

Tags: php, mysql

I stored the day(10), month(4) and year(1993) seperately. How do I compare it with the current date? If the date matches then send an email to myemail@gmail.com using cron.

**here is the code:**

```
<?php
include"connect_mysql.php";
$reminder_dates = mysql_query("SELECT*FROM registration_form");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($reminder_dates)){
$main_dob_day = $row['main_dob_day'];
$main_dob_month = $row['main_dob_month'];   
$main_dob_year = $row['main_dob_year'];
}
?>
```

Comment: `I stored the day(10), month(4) and year(1993) seperately. ` never do this! use datetime type!

Comment: Have you attempted any research? Maybe for a PHP function that would allow you to get todays date and month? \*cough\*[`date`](http://php.net/date)\*cough\*

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [**red box**](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is good PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Answer (score 1):

```
$main_date   = "{$main_dob_year}-{$main_dob_month}-{$main_dob_day}";
$todays_date = date("Y-m-d");
$today       = strtotime($todays_date);
$main_dt     = strtotime($main_date);

if($main_dt == $today)
{
  $valid = "send email";
  echo $valid;
}
```

it will work

Answer (score 0):

perhaps something like this:

```
$old_date = "2006-01-16"; // Create this from the 3 strings you have in the db
$old_date = strtotime($old_date); 

$todays_date = date("Y-m-d"); 
$todays_date = strtotime($todays_date); 


if ($old_date == $todays_date)
 print "equal";
else
 ....
```

edit: in repsonse to your comment, you can get the current day and month using the date function, like this:

```
$m = date("m");
$d = date("d");
```

Comment: how do I compare only the day and the month?

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick reply! hmm how do I remove the '0' infront of $m(07)? cause in the database my month is '7' instead of '07'.

Comment: @PSY Please learn to read the fine manual entry for [`date`](http://php.net/date).

Answer (score 0):

You can make the comparison right in the SQL query, then the loop would send out emails to all rows returned from the query:

```
<?php
    include"connect_mysql.php";
    $sql = "
        SELECT *
        FROM registration_form
        WHERE 
            main_dob_month = MONTH(CURDATE()) AND 
            main_dob_day = DAYOFMONTH(CURDATE())";

    $reminder_dates = mysql_query($sql);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($reminder_dates))
    {
        // send email(s)
    }
?>
```

Comment: Just be careful when sending lots of emails in a for loop, a lot of web hosts consider this as spammy behavior and may take action or blacklist your web servers ip address.